# Ruby - How do you perform an operation on each item of two (maybe more) arrays and populate them in a new array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, iterator, each, operations

```
a = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

each of array a's items are divided by each of array b's items and put into a new array called c.

```
c = [6, 3, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: `Array[a,b].transpose.map { |a, b| a / b }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

c = a.zip(b).map { |e| e.reduce :/ }
#⇒  [
#    [0] 6,
#    [1] 3,
#    [2] 2,
#    [3] 2,
#    [4] 2
# ]
```

[`Array#zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-zip) zips the arrays together and then each element (array of 2 items zipped) is reduced with `Integer#/`.

Comment: Why the unhappy face? :)

Comment: Is `.map { |e| e.reduce :/ }` better (faster, smarter etc) than `.map { |a,b| a/b }`?

Comment: @axiac no, but in my humble opinion is way more explicit. The intent is more clear.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Fool day ruby PR proposal: symbols should start with `:)` instead of `:`.

Comment: `a/b` looks easier to understand to me as a Ruby beginner. But after some reflection I must admit that using `.reduce :/` is more elegant; it allows wrapping everything into a method that gets the operation (`:/`, `:+` etc) as argument and can be reused this way.

Comment: It is always possible to add another level of indirection. :P

Comment: @axiac also it accepts 3 (or more) arrays as in input out of the box. Just change it to `a.zip(b, c, d)` and you are all set. For ten arrays and `:+` it would be annoying to write the sum explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I like mudasobwa's zip/map solution, but here are a couple alternatives:

```
a = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

c = Array.new(a.size) { |i| a[i] / b[i] }
c = a.map.with_index { |x, i| x / b[i] }
```

In particular, I might prefer the Array.new solution if the arrays aren't guaranteed to be the same length, because you can easily ensure you don't go over bounds:

```
c = Array.new([a.size, b.size].min) { |i| a[i] / b[i] }
```